# "Google Play Team" is check checking the wrong version - Background location access not declared

Tags: android, google-play

One of my app is using location while app is opened. It does not need/use any background location

The active version is 1.0.13 which targets android 8 or later versions

I've uploaded 1.0.15 which targets android 10 or later versions. I've also added

to AndroidManifest.xml file to make sure no background permission is used

The response from "google play team" is below

*Issue with your app
We’ve reviewed your app for compliance with all Location Permissions policy requirements (including use case eligibility), and found the following issues with your app:
Eligibility Issue
Background location access not declared
We detected that your app contains at least one feature that requests access to location in the background, however  your permission declaration form did not reflect this. Please log in to your Play Console to resubmit your location declaration form. You may either remove location in the background from your app or indicate that the usage is in the background.
**Affected APK(s):
APK:1013***

They say the "Affected APK is 1.0.13" . My "1.0.15" version is rejected because of "1.0.13"

How can i make "google play team" to review "1.0.15" version? This is weird

Any help is welcome

Comment: Try putting 1015 on all used tracks where 1013 is present.

Comment: There were "1.0.13" version for "Internal Test Track" which i have stopped

The rejection mail was not mentioning "internal test track".

Comment: Just try replacing all tracks with the new fixed version