# App removed by Google Play because older version is not compliant to new background location policy

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I have adjusted the permissions and use of location data and published it in a new release (v10004). Unfortunately, my app was still removed because the previous version does not comply with the new background location regulation (As described in the mail i got from Google: Affected APK(s): App Bundle:v10003).

I could not find a way to remove the old version, nor upload the new bundle in the old track (as recommended for example in ["Google Play Team" is check checking the wrong version - Background location access not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514856/google-play-team-is-check-checking-the-wrong-version-background-location-acc)).

It frustrates me quite a bit that the current publicly used version complies with all the guidelines, but it is not listed in the PlayStore, just because I have no way to modify the old track in the Google Play Console. I've been looking for a solution for almost 2 months now - Google support hasn't responded for weeks either.

Has anyone had a similar situation or been able to fix this issue somehow?

Thanks a lot for any suggestions how to solve this misery!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please follow the given steps to DEACTIVATE non-compliant APK (APK Version 25):

1. Go to your Play Console.
2. Select the app.
3. Go to App bundle explorer.
4. Select the non-compliant APK Version 25 at the top right dropdown menu, and make a note of which releases they are under.
5. Go to the track with the policy issue. It will be one of these 4 pages: Internal / Closed / Open testing or Production.
6. Near the top right of the page, click Create new release. (You may need to click Manage track first)
7. If the release with the violating APK is in a draft state, discard the release.
8. Add the policy compliant version of app bundles or APKs.
9. Make sure the non-compliant version of app bundles or APKs is under the Not included section of this release. For further guidance, please see the "Not included (app bundles and APKs)" section in this Play Console Help article.
10. To save any changes you make to your release, select Save.
11. When you've finished preparing your release, select Review release.
12. If the non-compliant APK is released to multiple tracks, repeat steps 5-9 in each track.
13. Please note that after you submit an update to an existing app on your Play Console, it can take some time for your app to be processed for standard publishing on Google Play. To check your submission status, you may follow the steps below:
14. Sign in to your Play Console.
15. Select your app.
16. On the left menu, select Release > Production or Testing (select the track(s) you have released)
17. If you're an AdMob publisher, please contact the AdMob team to re-enable ad serving.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly.

I didn't see that the apk is used in an internal test track (that was paused) - now my App is back in the PlayStore!

I wonder why Google didn't send this guideline to their users, when they changed the compliance for background location, only for admob.

Thanks anyway good sir, you saved my month!

Comment: Thanks! Google publishing is ridiculously convoluted. No much for Apple.

Comment: My god. This saved my life. Google has become more complicated now a days that Apple. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi , actually in my case version 65 which is in production . Now after resolving vulnerable issue we have updated app using above steps  even in internal , closed ,open and production but still play console is sending vulnerable issue is in version 65 and rejecting new updates. why?

Comment: Hi , Thanks ! finally updates got live..

Comment: If you've turned managed publishing on, you must set rollout of the new compliant release with "100%" to DEACTIVATE the previous non-compliant release.

Comment: Not able to follow step 9. i can't see the non include version section. please help.