# Google Play app rejected due to: Prominent disclosure Non compliant design for policy: Accessibility API

Tags: android, flutter, accessibility

Our application is getting rejected from the play store for policy violation regarding

**Prominent disclosure Non compliant design**

for **policy: Accessibility API**

[image]

Initially we were using 3rd party library cobrowse, and they were using

`android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE`

and our app got rejected, after that, we had removed the library itself and now no accessibility permission is being asked in our manifest, and to comply with prominent disclosure we had taken the following steps:

1. Added a Terms and conditions screen for all users.
2. Added UI for prominent disclosure when requesting all permissions.

[image][image]

Note: Even tho we are not using the accessibility API, we kept its content as our rejection reason was still accessibility API even after removing service and library.

Target SDK: 31

We tried updating content and adding prominent disclosure UI still, the app is not getting accepted.

It's been 5 weeks and still no update from google over playstore, and they do not reply to emails, chats.

Comment: after resolving everything like intent redirection should be trusted etc , you need to release your app like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67717994/app-removed-by-google-play-because-older-version-is-not-compliant-to-new-backgro